# In a lua for loop what is a # used for?

Tags: for-loop, lua

I know how for loops work and I use them quite often but also seem to often come across a # in others' code and I want to know what it is for and how to use it. An example of this would be:

```
for i = 1, #npc do local v = npc[i]
```

I cant seem to find anything online regarding this, maybe my searches just aren't good but it would be nice if someone could explain it for me, thanks.

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7

Comment: please note that asking for trivial things that can be found in the manual or by simply entering "lua # " into any websearch, are not well received. google for example auto completes "lua #" to "lua # operator" which yields several websites listing the meaning of all Lua operators.

Answer (score 3):

In Lua, `#` is the length operator. `for i = 1, #npc` essentially loops from 1 to the length of the `npc` array.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out, it gets the length of a list. However, there's another thing worth pointing out: that `for` loop is suboptimal and unidiomatic. It would be better written as `for i, v in ipairs(npc) do`. In general, using `#` in a `for` loop is almost always the wrong thing to do.